# Creating a div that wont take the whole width inside a bootstrap span class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to design a website with bootstrap where i need to place a small div with a colored background inside a (row-fluid, span class of bootstrap)

this is my code

```
    <style>
    .lblue{
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 
          0 1px 2px #fff, /*bottom external highlight*/
          0 -1px 1px #666, /*top external shadow*/ 
          inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /*bottom internal shadow*/ 
          inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8); /*top internal highlight*/
        font-size: 16pt;
        padding: 5px;
        margin:5px;
        color:white;
        background: #4bc2d3; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4bc2d3 0%, #70d6e2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4bc2d3), color-stop(100%,#70d6e2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4bc2d3 0%,#70d6e2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4bc2d3 0%,#70d6e2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4bc2d3 0%,#70d6e2 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4bc2d3 0%,#70d6e2 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4bc2d3', endColorstr='#70d6e2',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        font-family: OpenSans-Semibold;
        }
    </style>


    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
    <div class="lblue">Insert Content Here</div>
    <div class="lblue">Insert Content Here</div>
    <div class="lblue">Insert Content Here</div>
    <div class="lblue">Insert Content Here</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

the problem with this code is that the div class lblue takes the whole width of bootstrap's span12 class. I can't really assign a specific width for that div since it needs to be dynamic and stretches itself according to the length of its content.

summary:

1. i need to make the div class lblue to be only as long as the content inside it

is there a fix for this?

Comment: the fact is that main content gives your div the width, so i think you can't without specifing a fixed or percentage width

Comment: I've put all in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mGm5C/

Comment: it looks like what muller posted. is there a way to make those div's side by side and not on seperate rows?

Comment: yes if you set the width of the inner divs and then let span 12 be 100% use float-left for all inner div's and at the end <div style="clear:both"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an easy fix for your problem. Add the following to your .lblue:

```
display: table;
```

It should be compatible with most (if not all) browsers.

**Edit 1**

A bit more information on the topic can be found there:

http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout